# empty anchor tag inspite of loading value in blade syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my store cotroller i have the following function defined :

```
public function getProductspg() {
     return View::make('store.products')->with('product' , Product::all());
}
```

now in my main.blade.php , which is the index page, i have the following link:

```
 <li><a href="store/prodoctspg">products</a></li>
```

But however when i refresh my index page, I.E. `main.blade.php` , which is the page which has the above link , i still see the following:

```
<li><a href="">products</a></li>
```

Why ?

Comment: the code in your controller is showing the view store/products.blade.php and not main.blade.php

Comment: the link `<li><a href="store/prodoctspg">products</a></li>` is in the main.blade.php , which should link to products.blade.php ..

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
 <li><a href="{{ action('StoreController@getProductspg') }}">products</a></li>
```

and in the routes file create a route to your function:

```
Route::get('products', 'StoreController@getProductspg');
```